# How do you use jxl in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to read an xls file in jmeter using beanshell postprocessor. The error i get in the logs is: "Typed variable declaration : Class: Workbook not found in namespace"
Following is my code.

```
import java.io.*;
import jxl.Cell;  
import jxl.Sheet;  
import jxl.Workbook;  

FileInputStream(vars.get("jmeterScriptPath")+"\\"+vars.get("VIN")+".xls", true);

Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(new java.io.File("C:\\datasheet\\RIGUD000000000051.xls"));

Sheet sh = wb.getSheet("RIGUD000000000051"); 

        // To get the number of rows present in sheet
        int totalNoOfRows = sh.getRows();

        // To get the number of columns present in sheet
        int totalNoOfCols = sh.getColumns();

        for (int row = 0; row < totalNoOfRows; row++) {

            for (int col = 0; col < totalNoOfCols; col++) {
                System.out.print(sh.getCell(col, row).getContents() + "\t");
                vars.put("responseContent",sh.getCell(col, row).getContents());
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get it working follow next two steps:

1. Copy `jxl.jar` to JMeter's "lib" folder
2. Restart JMeter - it's required to pick the jxl.jar up.

You should be good to do with your code.

P.S. I would recommend to switch to [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) as JExcelApi supports only Excel 2003 documents and now is almost 2016. If you [download tika-app.jar](https://tika.apache.org/download.html) it will enable preview of all [supported formats](https://tika.apache.org/1.4/formats.html) in [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener and you also will get read/write access to them all from scripting test elements.

See [How to Extract Data From Files With JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/what-every-performance-tester-should-know-about-extracting-data-files-jmeter) guide for more information on working with binary files in JMeter.